# After recent update of Ubuntu 22.04 is not charging from docking station

Tags: windows, 22.04, power-management, docking

after recent update my laptop is not charging through docking station anymore when I am using Ubuntu and I need to use it with charging cable. I am also using Windows 11 on the same laptop and when I switch it on Windows charging works normally only through docking station. So I assume that there is a problem with Ubuntu not with laptop or docking station.
Laptop is HP Elitebook, docking station is HP USB-C G5 Essential Dock and ubuntu version is 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish).
Did anyone have similar problem? Thx for help!

Comment: Hi, have the exact same problem, my dell dock will not charge my Lenovo X1 Carbon g11. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: hi @RuneKaagaard sorry for late reply. I found out that it does charge my laptop only in case when battery level drops below 95%. Hope that helps!